# How to print out the distance from my function?

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I'm very new to C++. This is my first assignment, and I'm having trouble printing out (in `main()`) the final calculated distance `d` from my function `getairdistance()`. My program is shown below and I would appreciate any advice!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath> //for pi
using namespace std;
    
void getAirDistance(int *ptr, int *ptr1);
    
int main(){
    struct LOC{
        char loc_name[50]; //name of a location on earth
        double latitude; //latitude of this location
        double longitude; //longitude of this location
    }; //structure definition
    
    struct LOC location1;
    struct LOC location2; //declared two structures
    struct LOC *ptr, *ptr1; //declared two pointers
    ptr = &location1; //pointer to the first location structure
    ptr1 = &location2; //pointer to the second location structure
    
    cout << "Please enter the name of the first location: "; //print statement
    cin.getline(location1.loc_name, 50);//use getline to store the first location
    cout << "Please enter the latitude (degrees): "; //print statement
    cin >> location1.latitude; //use cin to get the first latitude
    cout << "Please enter the longitude (degrees): "; //print statement
    cin >> location1.longitude; //use cin to get the first longitude
    
    fflush(stdin);
    
    cout << "Please enter the name of the second location: ";
    cin.getline(location2.loc_name, 50);
    cout << "Please enter the latitude (degrees): ";
    cin >> location2.latitude;
    cout << "Please enter the longitude (degrees): ";
    cin >> location2.longitude; //exact same thing as above
    
    //getAirDistance(location1, location2);
    
    cout << "The air distance between " << location1.loc_name << " and " << location2.loc_name << " is appx. " << " km. "; //final print statement
}
    
void getAirDistance(int *ptr, int *ptr1){ //function definition
    double long1 = *(ptr + 2) * (M_PI/180); //longitude of first location (rad)
    double long2 = *(ptr1 + 2) * (M_PI/180); //longitude of second location (rad)
    double lat1 = *(ptr + 1) * (M_PI/180); //latitude of first location (rad)
    double lat2 = *(ptr1 + 1) * (M_PI/180); //longitude of first location (rad)
    double x = (long2 - long1) * cos((lat1 + lat2)/2); //x coordinate difference
    double y = lat2 - lat1; //y coordinate difference
    int R = 6371; //Radius of the earth
    int d = R * sqrt(pow(x, 2) + pow(y, 2)); //distance between the two locations
    cout << d;
}
```

Comment: ptr + 2 doesn't look right. that ptr is an int* but in the function main it's a location*. It's going to be pointing somewhere inside the char[50].

Comment: @sashang "*Its going to be pointing somewhere inside of `char[50]`*" - actually, it won't, because the code won't even compile to begin with.

Comment: @RemyLebeau technically what he's posted does compile.

Comment: @sashang Not when the call to `getAirDistance()` is uncommented, as `struct LOC` can't be assigned to `int*`

Comment: @RemyLebeau of course.

Answer (score 1):

Make your function `return` the value of `d` to the caller (ie `main()`), eg:

```cpp
int getAirDistance(int *ptr, int *ptr1);
    
int main(){
    ...
    
    int d = getAirDistance(...);
    
    cout << ... << d << ...;

    return 0;
}
    
int getAirDistance(int *ptr, int *ptr1){
    ...
    int d = ...;
    return d;
}
```

---

That being said, your function takes `int*` pointers as input, but there are no `int` variables in your `main()` code that can be passed to the function.  Your use of pointer arithmetic suggests that you think `+1` and `+2` are accessing the 1st and 2nd fields of the `LOC` struct, but that is not what happens at all.  I suspect what you really meant to do is something more like this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath> //for pi
using namespace std;
    
struct LOC{
    char loc_name[50]; //name of a location on earth
    double latitude; //latitude of this location
    double longitude; //longitude of this location
}; //structure definition

int getAirDistance(const LOC &loc1, const LOC &loc2);
    
int main(){
    LOC location1;
    LOC location2; //declared two structures
    
    cout << "Please enter the name of the first location: "; //print statement
    cin.getline(location1.loc_name, 50);//use getline to store the first location
    cout << "Please enter the latitude (degrees): "; //print statement
    cin >> location1.latitude; //use cin to get the first latitude
    cout << "Please enter the longitude (degrees): "; //print statement
    cin >> location1.longitude; //use cin to get the first longitude
    
    fflush(stdin);
    
    cout << "Please enter the name of the second location: ";
    cin.getline(location2.loc_name, 50);
    cout << "Please enter the latitude (degrees): ";
    cin >> location2.latitude;
    cout << "Please enter the longitude (degrees): ";
    cin >> location2.longitude; //exact same thing as above
    
    int d = getAirDistance(location1, location2);
    
    cout << "The air distance between " << location1.loc_name << " and " << location2.loc_name << " is appx. " << d << " km. "; //final print statement

    return 0;
}
    
int getAirDistance(const LOC &loc1, const LOC &loc2){ //function definition
    double long1 = loc1.longitude * (M_PI/180); //longitude of first location (rad)
    double long2 = loc2.longitude * (M_PI/180); //longitude of second location (rad)
    double lat1 = loc1.latitude * (M_PI/180); //latitude of first location (rad)
    double lat2 = loc2.latitude * (M_PI/180); //latitude of second location (rad)
    double x = (long2 - long1) * cos((lat1 + lat2)/2); //x coordinate difference
    double y = lat2 - lat1; //y coordinate difference
    int R = 6371; //Radius of the earth
    int d = R * sqrt(pow(x, 2) + pow(y, 2)); //distance between the two locations
    return d;
}
```